# Add a new row in order totals for Woocommerce Thankyou Page and emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have a problem with this code for add a row in email & thank you page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email( $total_rows, $myorder_obj ) {
    $total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Rec:', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => 'blabla'
    );
    return $total_rows;
}
```

I have a function to add "Total excl. VAT" row in the cart :

```
<?php 
    global $woocommerce;
    $frais = 1.01; 
    echo '<tr class ="totalht">
    <th>'. __( 'Total HT', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
    <td data-title=" '. __( 'Total HT', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">'
    . wc_price( ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total * $frais ) + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) .'<span class="ht-panier">HT</span></td>
    </tr>';
?>
```

It's working good : https://prnt.sc/irglky

But when I modify the first function :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email', 5, 2 );
function bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email( $total_rows, $myorder_obj ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $frais = 1.01;
    $price_excl_vat = wc_price( ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total * $frais ) + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total );
    $total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Total HT :', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => $price_excl_vat 
    );

    return $total_rows;
}
```

It's not working [on the Thank you page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSGqv.png)
But it's working [on email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqkTx.png)...

Someone can explain me why it's working on email but not in the "Thank you page"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** As this hook is for Order data, **but Not cart data**, you should try this instead, where I set the additional row before the last one:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_custom_order_totals_row', 30, 3 );
function add_custom_order_totals_row( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    $costs = 1.01;

    // Set last total row in a variable and remove it.
    $gran_total = $total_rows['order_total'];
    unset( $total_rows['order_total'] );

    // Insert a new row
    $total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Total HT :', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => wc_price( ( $order->get_total() - $order->get_total_tax() ) * $costs  ),
    );

    // Set back last total row
    $total_rows['order_total'] = $gran_total;

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). **Tested and works**.

[image]

---

For cart you should use this *(as `global $woocommerce;` is no longer needed)*:

```
<?php 
    $costs = 1.01; 

    echo '<tr class ="totalht">
    <th>'. __( 'Total HT', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
    <td data-title=" '. __( 'Total HT', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">'
    . wc_price( ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_total * $costs ) + WC()->cart->shipping_total ) .'<span class="ht-panier">HT</span></td>
    </tr>';
?>
```

Comment: @ArthurM Ok it was just a little typo error, try it now again.

Comment: @ArthurM Just maid another update, to make appear 'Total HT' before last 'Total' row… Try it. It works.